# how to get Merant 32-bit Progress SQL92 ODBC Driver

Tags: odbc, progress-db

I want to know how do I get Merant 32-bit Progress SQL92 ODBC Driver on my pc. I'm trying to connect progress 9.1D database using ODBC driver. But in my pc, I have no progress odbc driver.
 How do I get this driver? Any link?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Progress version 9.1d is, of course, ancient, obsolete and unsupported.  So finding up to date software for it can be a bit of a challenge.  Are you running it on Windows 98?

A cursory search of the knowledgebase at http://knowledgebase.progress.com/ reveals:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P29256?q=9.1d+odbc+driver&l=en_US&c=Product_Group%3AOpenEdge&fs=Search&pn=1

Of course that is the datadirect driver not Merant (Progress owns Datadirect).

But if you for some reason prefer Merant you could always try searching Google.  FWIW all of the results that I see look like dodgy "freeware" sites that are more likely to infect you with something than provide a working ODBC driver.